# How do i prove that a $m(TE)=0$ and $TE$ is measurable when $T$ is a singular operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $m^*$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\text{rank}(T)<n$ and $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then how do i prove that $m^*(T(E))=0$ and $T(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable?

I am studying two texts right now and they both say it's trivial, but i don't see how..

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $m^*(T(E))=0$ it is enough to prove that the measure of a hyper-plane is $0$. The hyperplane is a countable union of $n-1$ dimensional squares $Q$. $Q$ has measure $0$ because you can put infinitely many disjoint copies of $Q$ into an arbitrarily small box with height $\varepsilon>0$.

$T(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable because it is contained in a measurable set of $0$ measure.

Comment: it's in my text that $T(E)$ is lebesgue measurable even if $E$ is not.

Comment: @Mathems right... I've corrected my answer